# How to extract Virtual Table informations from a shared library?

Tags: c++, gcc, reverse-engineering

I'm implementing a performance analysis tool. One thing that I'm doing is to estimate the cost of a function call. In order to do that, I need to know if a given function is virtual in a shared library.

For that, I have access to the shared library assembly. I have also a call graph of the execution. I cannot make anything during the execution, the analysis has to be done after the execution using the information I can obtain from the call graph and the shared libraries.

The only way I've thought of is to extract the vtable from the library and look if my function is in the vtable, but I didn't find a way to extract the vtable of a class from the assembly.

I tried

```
readelf -s -W lib.so | c++filt | grep vtable
```

but that only give me an address of the good vtable (at least I think it's one) and this address lead me nowhere.

The shared library is compiled with gcc 4.3.5

Does someone know a way to obtain this vtable ? Or at least does someone know a way to know if a function is virtual in a shared library ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to know that unless you are trying to inherit from a particular class and override a method? (In which case you would find info in the header definition)

Comment: I'm working on an performance analysis tool and I need to know if a function is virtual to analyze the cost of the call to this function. And I don't have access to the sources

Comment: @Baptiste - why don't you try to trace the actual execution of the call and see if it is linked directly or uses a pointer reference for function address?

Comment: @littleadv what do you mean by tracing the execution ? At runtime ? How can I do that ? I've already a call graph that I analyze, this call graph is generated by callgrind

Comment: @Baptiste - you can do it at run time. Attach a debugger and put a break before the call to the function and just look at the assembly of the call. Call graph won't show dynamic dispatch, I'm guessing.

Comment: @littleadv the problem is that I need this information for every function of the call graph and I cannot debug the whole application

Comment: @Batpiste - then maybe you should refine the question a little bit with all the additional info you put in the comments here, it might help someone to come up with an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally we found a way to do that. It was not so complicated. In our case, the virtual tables addresses are in the .dynsym section of the ELF shared library file. And then the content of the virtual table is available on the .rela.dyn section. So we have to find the address and the size of every virtual table and then just read the .rela.dyn section to find the functions.

Of course, this is absolutely not portable, but in our case, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

0000000000400e80  w    O .rodata    0000000000000020              vtable for Test

i use the command "objdump -x a.out | c++ filt" and get the output above, obviously the vtable stored in the read only section as our expect. thank you for your advice.